# Expected Value of Cost of an experiment

Tags: probability

> When an experiment is performed, it has been determined that it will succeed with a probability of $0.8$ and will fail with probability of $0.2$. It costs \$10 to perform this experiment. However, if this experiment is successful, you earn$100. You perform the experiment several
>   times, independently, and stop as soon as you get one successful outcome.
>   You also stop if the first three attempts all fail. Let C be the cost of the
>   entire operation. Find the expected
>   value of C.

Thoughts include:

Since the experiment is a success or fail experiment, we can somehow express this as a Geometric distribution problem. Let $X$~ Bernoulli, where $P(\text{success})=0.8$, and $P(\text{failure})=0.2$.

At the same time, since it's also a problem where we will keep doing trials until a success, it can be viewed as geometric distribution as well...

The $\mathbb{E}(C)= -100*0.8+0.1x$?? where $x$ is number of trials done(not sure how to incorporate the fact that we will stop if 3 fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You onl have four possible outcomes:

- You win in your first try. The probability of this is $0.8$. You stop. The cost was $10\$$, and you won $100\$$, so $C=90$
- You fail the first try and win the second try. The probability of this happening is $0.2\cdot 0.8$. You then stop. The cost was $20\$$, so $C=80$
- You fail the first two tries, win the third one. $C=70$
- You Fail all three first tries, $C=-30$.